# Я учу filter, почему не работает код?

Tags: javascript, css, массивы, filter

```js
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
let c = elems.filter(function(currentValue, index){
    return currentValue.hasAttribute('class')
});

alert(c)
```

```html
<div class="item red"></div>
<div class="item green"></div>
<div class="item red"></div>
<div class="item blue"></div>
<div class="item red"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) возвращает не массив, а коллекцию. Поэтому у него просто нет этого метода.

Для того, чтобы он появился, нужно получить массив на основе этой коллекции, например используя метод [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
let elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item'));
let c = elems.filter(function(currentValue, index){
    return currentValue.hasAttribute('class');
 });

console.log(c);
```

```html
<div class="item red"></div>
<div class="item green"></div>
<div class="item red"></div>
<div class="item blue"></div>
<div class="item red"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо! А как делать так, чтобы оно выводило не [обджек], а напремер тег либо класс?

Comment: @РостиславКальченко, он и выводит html элемент, просто не надо для отладки использовать `alert`, который явно преобразовывает свой аргумент в строку.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1404966/191482  тут юзер завёл ещё один аккаунт. Надо смерджить