# Почему не работает вывод в алерт с фильтра?

Tags: javascript, массивы, dom

Не выводит текст в алерте с проверенного блока

```js
let elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item'));
let c = elems.filter(function(currentValue, index){
    return currentValue.classList.contains('red');
 });

alert(c.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="item red">1</div>
<div class="item green">2</div>
<div class="item red">3</div>
<div class="item blue">4</div>
<div class="item red">5</div>
```

Comment: У массива нет свойства `innerHTML`

Comment: И зачем было заводить нового пользователя?

Comment: Вопрос мучал, не дождался бы

Comment: а как то можно его добавить либо в текст преобразовать?

Comment: @КальченкоРостислав, новый аккаунт **не равно** уменьшение ожидания ответа. А вот правильная формулировка уже уменьшит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная `c` возвращает массив. И как уже сказали в комментариях - у массива нет ключа `innerHTML`.
Но он есть у элементов массива, следовательно проходим циклом по массиву и выводим `innerHTML`

```js
let elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item'));
let c = elems.filter(function(currentValue, index){
    return currentValue.classList.contains('red');
 });

console.info(c);

[...c].map(e => console.info(e.innerHTML));
```

```html
<div class="item red">1</div>
<div class="item green">2</div>
<div class="item red">3</div>
<div class="item blue">4</div>
<div class="item red">5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

filter применяется к массиву. Возвращает он тоже массив. А innerHTML должен применяться у конкретного элемента, а не у массива. В целом, для решения проблемы - надо в цикле пробежаться по массиву и взять у элементов то, что нужно

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Не проблема, сделаю через .map